# How to make a Network Folder remember its size and location

Tags: finder, mojave

I have two folders on my NAS that are shared between macs. However it seems every time the finder restarts, or logout, Mojave completely forgets their size (width x height) and placement (offset x,y) when I re-open them.

Is there some way to get the finder to know where and what size it should open shared network folders?

*Edit:*
The two folders in question are in List View, positioned to the bottom of the screen side by side of each other. When I re-open them after a reboot or finder restart (logout/in), then they are positioned way to the left lower of screen, wider, and short in height (clearly not where I left them).

---

I found some posts about how to get new finder windows to open in a size/location (which that I don't have any issues with)... but nothing about how to solve network folders.

Comment: What finder view are you using? What do you mean by size - size of icon or size of files on that share?

Comment: Make sure the network drive isn’t omitted from your spotlight settings.

Comment: What I do for windows that I always want to be in a certain location on the screen and size,  settings, etc., I use AppleScript to open these windows as I want them. It just makes it so much easier to deal with for the the really repetitive tasks with these windows. Food for thought.

Comment: @Mark Size of window, in pixels/placement (filesizes do not change).

Comment: @Theologin I have not removed anything from spotlight (yet) on this new mini/os install. Doublechecked, nothing is omitted from spotlight.

Comment: @user3439894 Do you have a link or hint how applescript can be done to do what you say? I would be fine putting two applescripts in my sidebar to open those windows, if it means they open where I want them :)

Comment: As an example, I have an AppleScript application with this [_example_ **AppleScript** _code_](https://paste.ee/p/8SQWD) in the Toolbar of Finder. It is one of many I have but this one when clicked, moves that window to a defined location, size and view, then opens another window to a defined location and size and view. To get the `bounds`, I setup my windows where I wanted them and then in Script Editor I used `tell application "Finder" to get {name, bounds} of every window` to get the window `name` and `bounds` for use in the actual _script_.

Comment: Have a look at [The Bounds Property](https://macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/11.html) for a clear explanation of the `bounds` _property_.